# hive create an array from string

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, casting, hiveql

In my data I have comma seperated strings. It would be much easier if these would be arrays, so I can easily match them with another array for example. However, I am not able to create an array from the string.

Example code:

```
create table tmp_array_string as
select '"abc", "def"' as tmp_string
      , array("abc", "def") as tmp_array

select a.*
     , array(tmp_string) as not_a_proper_array
     , size(tmp_array) as array_size
     , size(array(tmp_string) ) not_the_proper_array_size
from tmp_array_string a
```

Why is array(tmp_string not resulting in an array with 2 elements and is there a way to make this work?

Thanks a lot!

---

After leftjoins answer, here is the proof of the correctness. :-)

```
select a.*
     , array(tmp_string) as not_a_proper_array
     , split(regexp_replace(tmp_string,'"',''),',\\s*') as correct_array
     , size(tmp_array) as array_size
     , size(split(regexp_replace(tmp_string,'"',''),',\\s*')) as correct_size
     , size(array(tmp_string) ) not_the_proper_array_size
from tmp_array_string ater code here
```

correct size results in 2 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split(str, ',')` to get an array. See dosc: [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions)

```
select split('abc, def',',\\s*'); --Delimiter is comma+zero or more spaces
```

Result:

```
OK
["abc","def"]
Time taken: 1.676 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

If your delimited string contains extra  double quotes, then remove them using `regex_replace`:

```
 select split(regexp_replace('"abc", "def"','"',''),',\\s*');
```

Result:

```
OK
["abc","def"]
Time taken: 3.735 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very complet, correct and fast answer that really helped me. The array function on "abc","def" already creaeted an array, but as soon as the string was stored in a table as a column, the array function did not work anymore. However, split still worked.